# Deleting rows from 'table view' & 'filtered search bar' is not working

Tags: swift, tableview, searchbar, swift5

I'm making a music play app on Swift, which one could upload music from computer's web browser(GCD WebUploader) into the app's document dir. Now I could show all songs in table View and also the search bar is working correctly.

But I get issues when implement delete func. Ok, 2 questions.

1) when I swipe to delete a row from table view, then I could see that row is disappeared. But when I force this app and re-launch it then the deleted one is still there. -> Do I need to use async for all funcs or some database? I hit the wall and need help.

2) when I swipe to delete a row from search bar, the one is deleted from search bar, but when switch back, that song is still in the table view.

[image]

/// SongData.swift is using to store song's metaData.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SongData {
    var songName: String?
    var artistName: String?
    var albumName: String?
    var albumArtwork: UIImage?
    var url: URL?

    init(songName: String, artistName: String, albumName: String, albumArtwork: UIImage, url: URL) {
        self.songName = songName
        self.artistName = artistName
        self.albumName = albumName
        self.albumArtwork = albumArtwork
        self.url = url
    }

}
```

/// Table View Controller including the search bar

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation


class SongsTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating{

    var directoryContents = [URL]()
    var songName: String?
    var artistName: String?
    var albumName: String?
    var albumArtwork: UIImage?

    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

    // create type SongData array to store song's metaData.
    var tableData = [SongData]()
    var filteredTableData = [SongData]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        do {

            // Get the document directory url
            let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

            // Get the directory contents urls (including subfolders urls)
            directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)

            // if you want to filter the directory contents you can do like this:
            let mp3Files = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "mp3" }

            // get music metadata (artist, album...)
            for url in mp3Files {
                let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
                let metaData = asset.metadata

                if let songTitle = metaData.first(where: {$0.commonKey == .commonKeyTitle}), let value = songTitle.value as? String {
                    songName = value
                } else {
                    songName = "No song name"
                }

                if let artist = metaData.first(where: {$0.commonKey == .commonKeyArtist}), let value = artist.value as? String {
                    artistName = value
                } else {
                    artistName = "No artist name"
                }

                if let album = metaData.first(where: {$0.commonKey == .commonKeyAlbumName}), let value = album.value as? String {
                    albumName = value
                } else {
                    albumName = "No album name"
                }

                if let albumImage = metaData.first(where: {$0.commonKey == .commonKeyArtwork}), let value = albumImage.value as? Data {
                    albumArtwork = UIImage(data: value)
                } else {
                    albumArtwork = UIImage(named: "Apple")
                    print("artWork is not found!")
                }

                tableData.append(SongData(songName: songName!, artistName: artistName!, albumName: albumName!, albumArtwork: albumArtwork!, url: url))
            }

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        // add search bar
        resultSearchController = ({
            let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

            return controller
            })()

        // reload the table
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if resultSearchController.isActive {
            return filteredTableData.count
        } else {
            return tableData.count
        }

    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath)

        if resultSearchController.isActive {
            cell.textLabel?.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row].songName
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row].artistName
            cell.imageView?.image = filteredTableData[indexPath.row].albumArtwork
            return cell
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row].songName
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row].artistName
            cell.imageView?.image = tableData[indexPath.row].albumArtwork
            return cell
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if resultSearchController.isActive {
            do {
                // this part is not started yet
                try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: filteredTableData[indexPath.row].url!)
                audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                audioPlayer.play()
            } catch {
                print("could not load file")
            }
        } else {
            do {
                try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: directoryContents[indexPath.row])
                audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                audioPlayer.play()
            } catch {
                print("could not load file")
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
            if resultSearchController.isActive {
                filteredTableData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
            } else {
                tableData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
                // remove data from local source
                try! FileManager.default.removeItem(at: directoryContents[indexPath.row])
                print("delete song at index \(indexPath.row)")
            }
        }
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        filteredTableData.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

        let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text!
        for item in tableData {
            let str = item.songName
            if str!.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
                filteredTableData.append(item)
            }
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are deleting from only the filtered data array rather than removing from the the main array and from the app's directory hence the songs do not get deleted.

Comment: 1) You need to delete that song from the local file you use to create the dataSource i.e, `tableData`.  
2) Remove item from the source array `tableData` as well while deleting from `filteredTableData`

Comment: Unrelated but **never** declare properties in a class as optional which are initialized with non-optional values. Remove all question marks in `SongData`. The code will compile.

Comment: @Kamran, agree with u! I change my code to add file deleting on FileManager level, now deleting is working on table view. But for the search bar filter view, how could I know which one is supposed to be deleted from documentDirectory of app? I mean the index of filtered view will be different with the one in the local file.

Comment: @vadian, nice to see you again:) I will remove those question mark, trust me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conform `SongData` to `Equatable` as below,

```
class SongData: Equatable {

    static func == (lhs: SongData, rhs: SongData) -> Bool {
        return lhs.songName == rhs.songName &&
                lhs.artistName == rhs.artistName &&
                lhs.albumName == rhs.albumName &&
                lhs.albumArtwork == rhs.albumArtwork
    }

    var songName: String?
    var artistName: String?
    var albumName: String?
    var albumArtwork: UIImage?
    var url: URL?

    init(songName: String, artistName: String, albumName: String, albumArtwork: UIImage, url: URL) {
        self.songName = songName
        self.artistName = artistName
        self.albumName = albumName
        self.albumArtwork = albumArtwork
        self.url = url
    }
}
```

Now remove the `songData` object from the `tableData` while searching as below,

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
        if resultSearchController.isActive {
            let song = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]
            if let index = tableData.firstIndex(of: song) {
                try! FileManager.default.removeItem(at: directoryContents[index])
                tableData.remove(at: index)
            }

            filteredTableData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
        } else {
            tableData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
            // remove data from local source
            try! FileManager.default.removeItem(at: directoryContents[indexPath.row])
            print("delete song at index \(indexPath.row)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, it let me know this `tableData.firstIndex(of: song)`  method, as I'm rookie to Swift and learn alone, to find which API/library to use and how to implement them really took me loads of time, but thanks for Google and stackoverflow, giving me a way to find the answer. Ps. `tableData.firstIndex(of: song)` requires Equatable types but I don't change my song data, I found another solution `tableData.firstIndex(where: { $0.songName == selected_song.songName })`. Well I will update my code as below(after test on iPhone), thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, update my code here. As Kamran's method, to use tableData.firstIndex(of: song) to compare the selected song in search bar with song in tableData. But I don't use the Equatable in my SongData file. For real, I don't fully understand this grammar now `static func == (lhs: SongData, rhs: SongData) -> Bool{}`, would like to improve and learn it later.

/ / / The code is kind of messy with a lot of comments, I just want to make the things clear. In short, when deleting a song/row in search bar, u need to delete the the song from your local file, data source, filtered data source and also the directoryContents which is an URL array using to play the song in my app.

Note! If two song have same name, then my solution will failed.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
            if resultSearchController.isActive {
                // get selected song from search bar
                let selected_song = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]
                // get song index in tableData where condition is
                // tableData's item.songName == selected song's songName
                if let index = tableData.firstIndex(where: { $0.songName == selected_song.songName && $0.albumName == selected_song.albumName}) {
                    // remove data from local source
                    try! FileManager.default.removeItem(at: directoryContents[index])
                    // remove url item from dir contents [URL], which is using for audio playing
                    directoryContents.remove(at: index)
                    // remove song from tableData
                    tableData.remove(at: index)
                }

                // remove song from filteredTableData
                filteredTableData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                // delete row with selected song from tableView in search bar
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
            } else {
                tableData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
                // remove data from local source
                try! FileManager.default.removeItem(at: directoryContents[indexPath.row])
                // remove url from dir contents [URL], which is using for audio playing
                directoryContents.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                print("delete song at index \(indexPath.row)")
            }
        }
    }
```